# How do I loop the JSON Request with different customer object data in Postman?

Tags: loops, testing, interface, postman

How do I loop the JSON Request with different customer object data in POSTMAN?
I'm looking to load a web application with test data.

```
{
  "customer": {
   "external_id": "EXT1221",
    "name": "Elon Musk",
    "address": "1405 North Ave, Chicago",
        "address_second_line": "Apt 2",
    "phone": "522-525-5555",
    "email": "elon@company.com",
    "zipcode": "60612",
    "lat": "40.7833404",
    "lng" : "-73.9527781",
    "merchant_id" : 11271,
    "confirmation_code" : "5320",
    "allow_login" : true,
    "allow_sending_email" : true,
    "allow_sending_sms" : true,
    "language": "en"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not defined structure how you would like to keep data. It looks like you are assuming data will be like :

```
{
  "customers": {
    "external_id": "EXT1221",
    "name": "Elon Musk",
    "address": "1405 North Ave, Chicago",
    "address_second_line": "Apt 2",
    "phone": "522-525-5555",
    "email": "elon@company.com",
    "zipcode": "60612",
    "lat": "40.7833404",
    "lng": "-73.9527781",
    "merchant_id": 11271,
    "confirmation_code": "5320",
    "allow_login": true,
    "allow_sending_email": true,
    "allow_sending_sms": true,
    "language": "en"
  },
  "customer": {
    "external_id": "EXT1222",
    "name": "Elon Musk2",
    "address": "1405 North Ave, Chicago",
    "address_second_line": "Apt 2",
    "phone": "522-525-5555",
    "email": "elon2@company.com",
    "zipcode": "60612",
    "lat": "40.7833404",
    "lng": "-73.9527781",
    "merchant_id": 11271,
    "confirmation_code": "5320",
    "allow_login": true,
    "allow_sending_email": true,
    "allow_sending_sms": true,
    "language": "en"
  }
}
```

In this case you can iterate as below :

Assuming testData is storing this JSON data.

```
_.each(testData,function(value,key){
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(key)} ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
})
```

There is another way to do if JSON looks like as below :

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "external_id": "EXT1221",
      "name": "Elon Musk",
      "address": "1405 North Ave, Chicago",
      "address_second_line": "Apt 2",
      "phone": "522-525-5555",
      "email": "elon@company.com",
      "zipcode": "60612",
      "lat": "40.7833404",
      "lng": "-73.9527781",
      "merchant_id": 11271,
      "confirmation_code": "5320",
      "allow_login": true,
      "allow_sending_email": true,
      "allow_sending_sms": true,
      "language": "en"
    },
    {
      "external_id": "EXT1222",
      "name": "Elon Musk2",
      "address": "1405 North Ave, Chicago",
      "address_second_line": "Apt 2",
      "phone": "522-525-5555",
      "email": "elon2@company.com",
      "zipcode": "60612",
      "lat": "40.7833404",
      "lng": "-73.9527781",
      "merchant_id": 11271,
      "confirmation_code": "5320",
      "allow_login": true,
      "allow_sending_email": true,
      "allow_sending_sms": true,
      "language": "en"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can iterate for each customer as below:

assuming testData storing above JSON.

```
_.each(testData.customers,function(customer){
    console.log(customer);
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the response.   I got an error when trying both.   "There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  ReferenceError: testData is not defined"

Comment: I have already mentioned "assuming testData storing above JSON."   instead of testData, use the variable which is holding that JSON structure.